# concourse-web service error "message":"atc.db.failed-to-open-db-retrying"

Tags: postgresql, concourse

I followed the https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-concourse-ci-on-ubuntu-16-04

to install concourse on my local machine VM.

I checked the status of the concourse-web service but I see the service is started but there is this error message in the log.

concourse-web.service - Concourse CI web process (ATC and TSA)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/concourse-web.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-12-12 02:46:58 PST; 6h ago
 Main PID: 6632 (concourse)
   CGroup: /system.slice/concourse-web.service
           └─6632 /usr/local/bin/concourse web

Dec 12 09:14:24 ubuntu concourse[6632]: {"timestamp":"1513098864.594436169","source":"atc","**message":"atc.db.failed-to-open-db-retrying","log_level":2,"data"**

At the same time I see postgresql service is running fine  but when try to create any user see the following error

root@ubuntu:/home/shishir# sudo -u postgres createuser concourse
Can't locate PgCommon.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PgCommon module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /usr/bin/createuser line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/createuser line 21.

awaiting any help in this direction

Comment: did you fix the issue by any chance? I've run into the same one!

Comment: Same issue here. Did anyone fix this

Answer (score 0):

double check if you have a postgres docker image lurking. If so remove it with `docker rm <image>` and make Concourse download it again. This fixed the issue for me.

So, after doing this, it looks like Concourse runs for a short time and then crashes. Not sure what the issue is, but I will investigate.

Comment: I'm now running into that issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. There's no other postgres container running, in fact, concourse is the only docker stuff i've got running there. I do have the feeling that something with the networking is broken somehow, as I'm also getting a 502 when trying to access concourse over the web and my nginx is telling me `recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream`. Any idea what could be the problem?